How can chaotic dynamics be integrated into spacetime perturbations in GR, using nonlinear systems, without violating the fundamental principles?
I have a very intriguing idea, probably more of a mathematical curiosity :
In General Relativity (GR), spacetime curvature is described by Einstein's field equations, which are inherently nonlinear. However, most perturbation studies linearize these equations, simplifying the analysis but neglecting potential chaotic behaviors that might arise from the full nonlinear dynamics.
I am exploring the idea of introducing chaotic dynamics into the perturbations $h_{\mu\nu}$ of the metric tensor, where $g_{\mu\nu} = \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} + \epsilon h_{\mu\nu}$, and $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ is the background metric. Instead of evolving $h_{\mu\nu}$ linearly, I propose modeling its evolution with nonlinear systems such as $\frac{dX}{dt} = f(X)$, where $X$ represents variables related to the perturbation modes, and $f(X)$ can represent a chaotic system like the Lorenz equations.
I have a few questions associated with this idea :

How can nonlinear systems like the Lorenz equations be adapted or derived from the full Einstein equations for perturbations $h_{\mu\nu}$? Is it valid to impose such dynamics on $h_{\mu\nu}$, and how can this be justified physically?

What methods or tools are best suited to simulate chaotic dynamics in the perturbations of General Relativity, particularly when handling the sensitivity to initial conditions?

What are some possible signatures of chaotic spacetime perturbations that could be detectable, for instance, in gravitational wave data or cosmological anisotropies?

How can this approach remain consistent with the principles of GR, such as covariance and energy conservation, without introducing arbitrary external dynamics to the system?

If the perturbations grow chaotically, how can we ensure the small perturbation approximation remains valid, or what frameworks exist to handle large chaotic perturbations?


Why
In revious studies, like the chaotic behavior in Bianchi IX (mixmaster) models or in black hole systems, focus on chaos emerging globally from spacetime dynamics. Here, we embed chaos directly within the perturbations, leveraging Einstein’s nonlinear equations to explore local chaotic evolution.
To offer a fresh perspective on how small perturbations in spacetime could lead to significant long-term effects. It could provide insights into phenomena such as irregularities in gravitational waves, black hole dynamics, or cosmological anisotropies, and might offer a new perspective on the interplay between General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics by highlighting the role of sensitivity to initial conditions.
I would appreciate any help //feedbacks :)
